# Fibonacci program in Scheme (using define-datatype)

Tags: types, scheme, fibonacci

I have been trying to write the Fibonacci program in scheme using the **define-datatype** approach but am unable to do so. Please tell me how its done.

I have written the representation independence code below:

```
(define (top-k k)
   k)

(define (applyk k n)
  (k n))

(define (fibind n k)
  (cond
   [(= n 0) (k 1)]
   [(= n 1) (k 1)]
   [else (fibind (- n 1) (fib1 n k))]))

(define fib1
  (lambda (n k)
    (lambda (v)
      (fibind (- n 2) (lambda (w) (k (+ v w)))))))
```

**EDIT:** I basically want a code (similar to the one below) that finds fibonacci numbers

```
;;;;k:: []-> continuation?
(define-datatype k k?
 [topk]
 [fact1-k (n number?) (saved-k k?)])

;;;appylk:: nat? continuation? -> nat?
(define apply-k
  (lambda (v c)
  (cases k c
   [topk () v]
   [fact1-k (n saved-k)
      (apply-k (* n v) saved-k)])))

;;;fact :: nat? continuation? -> nat? 
(define (fact n k)
   (if (< n 2)
      (apply-k n k)
      (fact (- n 1) (fact1-k n k))))
```

Comment: What's the "define-datatype" approach?  The code you've shown looks like it's continuation passing style, though not (as you know) correct…

Comment: Actually the above code works. Its a CPS version that finds the nth Fibonacci number.
You may attempt it using : (fibind 5 top-k) or putting any number n instead of 4.

Comment: Oh, sorry, then.  I assumed that since you said you were unable to write the code, and posted some code, that the code you posted didn't work.  My mistake.  Can you clarify what it is that you're _trying_ to do, then?

Comment: I added a sample code for the factorial function. I need something similar for Fibonacci.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code, we are not here to solve your homework problems.

Comment: It wasn't a homework problem. I was trying it out on my own and wasn't getting any ideas. Thanks for the solution though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for fibonacci CPS Representation Independence,

```
#lang racket

(define top-k
  (lambda(v)
    v))

(define fib
  (lambda (n)
    (fib/k n top-k)))

(define fib/k
  (lambda (n k)
    (cond 
      [ (= 1 n)
                (apply-k k 0) ]
      [ (= 2 n)
                (apply-k k 1) ]

      (else
           (fib/k (sub1 n) (fib1-k n k) )
      )
    )
  )
)

(define fib1-k
  (lambda (n k)
    (lambda(v)
      (fib/k (- n 2) (fib2-k v k))
      )))


(define fib2-k
  (lambda(v k)
    (lambda (w)
      (apply-k k (+ w v))
    )))



(define apply-k
  (lambda(k v)
    (k v)))
```

For details refer page 198 of book  [Essentials of Programming Languages](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262062798)

I do not know what you are calling as representation independent is really so or not.

Answer (score 4):

Your code makes it look like you're trying to do this in continuation passing style.  First, let's take a look at the naïve direct way of implementing the `n`th Fibonacci number:

```
(define (fib n)
  ;; This is a naïve implementation, and will get 
  ;; *very* slow, *very* quickly.  It's much more 
  ;; common to implement this as an iterative process
  (cond
    ((= n 0) 1)
    ((= n 1) 1)
    (else (+ (fib (- n 1))
             (fib (- n 2))))))
```

Now, to translate that into continuation passing style, we just break down where certain things happen. For the cases that `n` is `0` or `1`, we just call the continuation with `1`.  On the recursive case, though, we need to compute the Fibonacci number for `(- n 1)` (call it `f1`), and call some continuation with it.  That continuation isn't `k` though, since there's still work to be done; we still need the number for `(- n 2)`!  The continuation takes `f1` as an argument, and computes the Fibonacci number of `(- n 2)` for us (call it `f2`) and must call some continuation with it.  That continuation isn't `k`, either, though.  The new continuation will have access to `f1` and `f2` though, and their sum is what `k` needs:

```
(define (fib% n k)
  (cond
    ((= n 0) (k 1))
    ((= n 1) (k 1))
    (else (fib% (- n 1)
                (lambda (f1)
                  (fib% (- n 2)
                        (lambda (f2)
                          (k (+ f1 f2)))))))))
```

```
> (fib% 1 display)
1
> (fib% 5 display)
8
> (fib% 8 display)
34
```

There are much more efficient ways to compute numbers in the Fibonacci sequence, though.  The typical one starts with 1 and 1, then computes the next value (2), adds that to the previous value (1) to get 3, adds that the previous value (2) to get 5, adds that to the previous value (3) to get 8, and so on.  That looks like:

```
(define (fib-it n)
  ;; This is much more efficient, since it moves
  ;; computes the numbers in the sequence sequentially.
  (let fib ((a 1) (b 1) (n n))
    (if (zero? n)
        a
        (fib b (+ a b) (sub1 n)))))
```

This is already pretty much in a continuation passing style, except that the named `let` function, `fib`, returns `a` instead of calling `k` with it. This could be done with:

```
(define (fib-it% n k)
  (let fib ((a 1) (b 1) (n n))
    (if (zero? n)
        (k a)
        (fib b (+ a b) (sub1 n)))))
```

This doesn't feel like it's accomplished as much, because it's a continuation passing style version of a function that didn't make any self-recursive calls anyhow;  the iteration with the named `let` took care of that.  We might as well have written the following, but it's not much fun:

```
(define (fib-it% n k)
  (k (let fib ((a 1) (b 1) (n n))
       (if (zero? n)
           a
           (fib b (+ a b) (sub1 n))))))
```